# MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error

Tags: error-handling, ethereum, solidity, metamask, nft

I am developing a NFT Minting Website on CELO. My mint function looks like this:

```
function safeMint(address to) public payable {
    require(msg.value >= mintPrice, "Not enough ETH sent; check price!"); 
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
   // string memory token_uri=tokenURI(tokenId);
}
```

My react front end looks like this:

```
async function mintNFT() {

if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
  
  await requestAccount()
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(t_tokenAddress, Token.abi, signer);
  
  try{
    await window.ethereum.enable();
  const transation = await contract.safeMint(userAccount);
  await transation.wait();
  fetchNFTIndex();
}
catch(e){
  console.log(e.data.message);
 }
}
```

}

I get the following error when I run the transaction with mintPrice =1 wei or ether:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irSmh.png)

When I run the transaction with mintPrice=0 ether or wei it works fine. I dont know what is the problem here. I have 5 celos in my account so I have enough funds, I assume that ethers are converted and paid in CELO.
Can anyone understand the problem here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked error contains the custom message "Not enough ETH sent", which means the error originates from the `require()` condition.

```
require(msg.value >= mintPrice, "Not enough ETH sent; check price!");
```

Your JS snippet executes the function, but doesn't send any ETH value with the transaction.

In order to send ETH value, you need to define it in the [overrides](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-functionsSend) parameter.

```
const transation = await contract.safeMint(userAccount, {
    // send along 1 wei
    value: 1
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The transaction works correctly now.

Comment: I want to mint the NFT for 1 ether not in wei. I have used this code to accomplish this const transation  = await contract.safeMint(account_address, {
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"). However it dosent work as in this case I send 0.1 ethers and my contract requires 1 ether but still the transaction is successful. Do u know if there is a turn around for this

Comment: @Maliha I don't see a requirement for 1 ETH in your original code. You can add it like this: `require(msg.value >= 1 ether);`